# Linux "sem_wait" pseudocode?

Tags: linux

What i really want to know is if    `sem_wait()`    is "no busy waiting" or not.  Does a thread wastes CPU cycles if it is waiting for its requested resource in    `sem_wait()`.

Comment: No, `sem_wait` does not busy wait. It suspends the process if it needs to block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the synchronization primitives add the thread to a wait queue and then put it to sleep. When the resource is available it wakes up one or more threads which will subsequently try the request again and may or may not be put back to sleep depending on whether they acquired the requested resource.